# TableLayout not skipping column 0 when setting android:layout_column = "1"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

The xml code on this site: http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/6/
Gives the table layout shown in the image.

http://www.learn-android.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/TableLayout.png

But if you remove the first table row, then the First Name textview appears in column 0 even though its android:column_layout is set to "1"

But on this site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html it says "If you skip a column number, it will be considered an empty cell in that row."

IF you want a empty cell in the row, do you have to fill it in with something or set its width?

Is there a better way to get things spaced in the middle of the screen like in the table row?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the empty cell is there, it just has no width. If there is nothing with a nonzero width, it will look like there is no column 0. To get it to take up some space, there needs to be something there, even if its just an empty View with a width set.

If you want things centered, it might make sense to use a RelativeLayout and use either `android:layout_gravity="center"` or `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to align things in the center of the screen.

Comment: So having the button in the top row gives column 0 a width, and this is spread to subsequent columns.

Comment: Correct. Because the width of everything in that layout is set to `wrap_content`, it makes it 0 width to fit the 0 width of content.

Comment: Does the RelativeLayout get the android:layout_gravity ="center" or the textview?  EDIT: Oh I see.  I put it in the RelativeLayout but I also had to set the RelativeLayout's width to wrap_content instead of match_parent

Comment: Generally, anything with `layout_` at the beginning describes how a View is situated within the parent. So in this case, set it on the View you want to be centered.